# How do I set an HTML data- attribute to the value of a dropdown button?

Tags: jquery, html

Every post that I read is how to work out the jQuery code, but I have that down:

```
<button id ="seButton" data-value="????" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Options<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu noclose">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_1" name="ex3" value="1" checked="">
      <label for="ex3_1">Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_2" name="ex3" value="2">
      <label for="ex3_2">Option 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_3" name="ex3" value="3">
      <label for="ex3_3">Option 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#seButton').click(function() {
    var se = $(this).attr('data-value');

    console.log("se equals " + se);    
  });
});
</script>
```

I'm grabbing `data-value` just fine, but I don't know how to SET data-value in the first place to capture the options that the user might be selecting.  I'm using Bootstrap's `noclose` so the user is able to select MULTIPLE options if they so desire.  I'd like the JavaScript var to be equal to whatever options they select....

## Update

I sorted this out by doing changing the script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var seSelection = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-menu input").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest("#seButton").data();
        if (this.checked) {
        seSelection.push(this.value);
        }

    console.log("se equals " + seSelection);    
  });
});
</script>
```

I defined an array prior to `$(document).ready` then pushed each value I had selected to that.  I'm sure there's a better way, but this works in the event anyone else reads this thread looking for a solution!

Comment: What's wrong with `attr()` documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first get the value from the inputs you click, then set that value to the button. Try doing this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu input").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest("#seButton").data('value', value);
    });
```

Comment: Hmm - this is great, thank you.  However, it's not allowing for the multiple selections to occur.  I'm getting a `console.log` of `button value is 1` or `button value is 5`.  Since my drop-down doesn't close on its own, (to allow for multiple selections,) how do I get this to only register once the user has clicked OFF the drop-down, and incorporate all of the choices they've made?

Answer (score 1):

You can set data value like this:

```
$(this).data('value', valueToSet);
```

and get like this:

```
$(this).data('value');
```

.data assumes it start with data- so data('value') is the same as attr('data-value')

Comment: Please note, this won't set attribute value, but jq data object property

Comment: where would I find the documentation on this?  i'd love to read through it to get a better understanding

Comment: even after reading through this, I'm not sure how to assign multiple clicked items into my variable...